# Does the starting seed matter for sql server identity column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, primary-key

Are there any technical considerations when setting the seed value for an identity column in SQL server?

This column will be the PK and marked as Identity auto increment.

The business does not want to start IDs at 1 because they will be publicly visible in query strings and displayed on several pages. Using a higher random number makes it look better, this all makes sense to me and I want to make sure I am not missing any technical considerations.

This is an example of what I am going to do

```
--Reset manufacturer id to a Random 5 digit number
DECLARE @newId INT = (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 100000) + 10000  % 10000) 
DBCC CHECKIDENT (Manufacturer, RESEED, @newId );
```

Comment: Well, RESEED can be a problem if you already have values in the table.ID column.  Generally, you need to make sure that it is higher than existing values. (Lower can work too, but it's more complicated)

Comment: This kind of thing should NOT be visible in a query string. That is a big red flag that your code is not designed well. This potentially means that users can change the querystring and see data belonging to somebody else. And honestly this should generally not be a value that the users should see. There is no technical reason that you can't start it at whatever value you want. But keep in mind that you can and will get large gaps periodically.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thats right, my tables will be completely empty

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange, can't you use a dummy guid / `unique_identifier` to be used for references from outside the database?

Comment: @SqlZim I think my example is misleading, sorry for that. The real entities this will be used on are fully public and searchable, similar to SO questions and their IDs. It will work something like `http://mysite/search/details?id=83833`. Also some printable documents relating to the entity will carry the ID, something like `Report#: 83833`. We could create some alias that isn't the PK and it something to consider.

Comment: Since there isn't the security risk of private data this is a lot less of an issue. Why not just start your identity values with a value, not much point in making it random. Perhaps 42259299 (The ID from this question), or 83833 from your previous comment? :D

Comment: Tagging along with @SeanLange ... or not so random like the first x digits of pi, or the golden ratio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing some comments into an answer.

The starting Identity value needs to consider any values already in the table. Because the ID will auto increment it might collide with already existing values if the ID is seeded too low.

Large gaps may appear in the sequence of Ids. However unlikely, a high starting seed and many gaps might lead to exhaustion of the INT range for the column. Then the app goes boom!

Any indexes on the column shouldn't care if it starts at 1 or 99999.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with starting at some random future number.